# Does "I swear..." constitute an oath?

Tags: terminology, oaths

I am a Muslim and I am thinking about if I said "I swear to/that..." will it be considered as an Islamic oath (like saying (in Arabic) "oqsm b Allah")?

I might need to say that to somebody who is not a Muslim, so I can't use "I swear to Allah".

Comment: You mean like saying; "I swear that I saw him yesterday!" In that case it's not an issue. The issue is when you swear on things or people i.e considering them somehow holy. Abaokom in the famous hadith can also mean our dead grandfathers i.e our dead "holy" grandfathers or something similar. So the hadith is actually saying don't swear on your forefathers, it's kind of a sadd dira' blocking the way to a haram (something that *might* develop to shirk, and the arabs that time just got out of shirk so there was a fear of that).... but in the case of just swearing then the context is not the same

Answer (score -1):

Salam,

No you must say i swear to God, otherwise don't swear... whatever your interlocutor.

Note this Hadith from the two sahih ([1](http://www.binbaz.org.sa/node/1703)):
"

> إن الله ينهاكم أن تحلفوا بآبائكم فمن كان حالفاً فليحلف بالله أو ليصمت و الله  تعالى أعلم

```
God inhibits you swearing to your ancients, 
But if you do then swear to God or don't swear at all .
And Gods knows best
```

Comment: Lack of reference!! Do you think?! he wants any reference not your idea, man...

Comment: I edited the answer. Maybe is there someone who can translate to English if it is necessary...

Comment: Why still downvote ?

Comment: I'm innocent!! I remove my downvote...